# Get HTML Code after logging into Website via Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get the HTML code of a website after I log in. The website is only accessible from a local network.

The code I get is from the login-site.

My script looks like this:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://192.168.135.189/mysite/check_mk/login.py")
$ie.visible = $true

while($ie.busy) {start-sleep 1}

#login
$ie.Document.getElementById("input_user").Value = "cmkadmin"
$ie.Document.getElementById("input_pass").Value="xxxx"


while($IE.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
#Click-Button
$ie.document.getElementByID('_login').Click()

while($IE.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
$IE.navigate("http://192.168.135.189/mysite/check_mk/index.py?start_url=%2Fmysite%2Fcheck_mk%2Fview.py%3Fhost%3D192.168.135.189%26site%3Dmysite%26view_name%3Dhost") 

while($IE.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}

#Fetch Site
$WebFetch = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://192.168.135.189/mysite/check_mk/index.py?start_url=%2Fmysite%2Fcheck_mk%2Fview.py%3Fhost%3D192.168.135.189%26site%3Dmysite%26view_name%3Dhost"

#Typename
$WebFetch | Get-Member

#RawContent
$WebFetch.RawContent

$WebFetch.AllElements | where tagname -EQ "Memory"
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Any error log would help.

Comment: The problem is that i get the HTML-code of the log-in site. I want the code of the site AFTER log in. :)

Comment: Why would you not try to work with the IE object and instead make a completely separate request that's going to miss any cookies and such?

Comment: Possible to get whole HTML with IE object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6590026/seth) comment has a good point. Are you passing login page with ie com object?
If the answer is yes, you can simply do:

```
$ie.Document.documentElement.outerHTML > "C:\some\path\to\save.html"
```

You can also use variable:

```
$sourceHTML = $ie.Document.documentElement.outerHTML
```